# Installing Git with non-root user account

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu

I've already set up a Git repository on GitHub and committed a few changes from my Windows machine.

But tomorrow I'll have to work in this repository from a machine running Ubuntu with limited privilege (i.e. no sudo).

Is there a portable version of Git for Linux? Or some source that allows me to compile and install Git only for the current user?

Comment: Why not just install it in your home directory instead of /usr/bin?

Comment: If this is the only reason for using sudo during installations (as it now seems to be), I wasn't aware of that at all.

Comment: Here is a nice step by step guide:
[http://joemaller.com/908/how-to-install-git-on-a-shared-host/](http://joemaller.com/908/how-to-install-git-on-a-shared-host/)

Comment: You certainly can, but first I'd ask the owner of the machine to install git (`sudo apt-get install git`).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can download the git source and do `make configure && ./configure --prefix=/home/user/myroot && make && make install` to install git to your home directory provided you have the build tools.  If you don't have the build-essential package installed (`dpkg --list|grep build-essential`), you will need to install those to your home directory as well.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using .git as the directory you install into, that just seems like it's asking for confusion (as git uses directories named .git to store the repo data for a non-bare repos).

Comment: Ironically, by default Git configures itself to install into home directory.

Comment: If you can't find `configure` in the sources directory, you might have to run `make configure` beforehand (I did). Hope this helps!

Comment: Make sure to download a version that is compatible to your system. Latest isn't necessary the most proper...

Comment: The INSTALL text file has many useful details. My remote non-sudo machine didn't have libcurl4-dev so I used "NO_CURL" option.

Comment: actually it says that you have to ```make configure``` first, so you can use configure

Comment: @Scott, Is there a place to download git compiled binaries and just extract them? No installation or compilation. Just download it as you download ant other binary TAR.

Comment: @Scott, On their website I couldn't find compiled binaries. Can you?

Comment: @Royi what operating system? If you're using a Linux distribution, just use your package manager or download source and a create statically linked binary.

Comment: I'm newbie on Linux. Hence I wondered if someone created such thing to use it. I tried following some tutorials but it seems that they are outdated as the file generated doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Royi which distro of Linux?

Comment: @Scott, It's Linux Mint 18.2. I know I can install it using the package manager but I would like to have it in not system wide installation as I have only one program which uses it (SmartGit).

Comment: @Royi then you'll have to install it from source using the instructions on the website; it's not that hard and will be a good learning experience for you

Comment: how would you download git source?

Comment: @Rainb, here: https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/

Answer (score 19):

I don't like link-only answers, but [this](http://joemaller.com/908/how-to-install-git-on-a-shared-host/) link I followed step-by-step on a Fedora machine and it worked without modification.  Very, very easy.  The binaries end up in your ~/bin directory.  You download a tarball, extract the sources, run `make` and run `make install` and that is it.

As the author states, the 2 prerequisites are gcc and ssh and if you meet these git should work for you as a non-root user.

Comment: Exactly! `--prefix` defaults to home install now, no need for it for this use case, tested v2.30.1.

Answer (score 15):

To install git and dependencies from source the following maybe useful.

Replace  with the location you are installing your non-root apps and consider checking for latest versions of source code.

```
wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.47.1.tar.gz
tar -xf curl-7.47.1.tar.gz
mkdir <local_curl_dir>
cd curl-7.47.1
./configure --prefix=<local_curl_dir>
make
make install

wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
tar -xf expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
mkdir <local_expat_dir>
cd expat-2.1.0
./configure --prefix=<local_expat_dir>
make
make install

wget https://github.com/git/git/archive/v2.6.4.tar.gz
tar -xf v2.6.4
mkdir <local_git_dir>
cd git-2.6.4
make configure
./configure --prefix=<local_git_dir>/git --with-curl=<local_curl_dir>/curl --with-expat=<local_expat_dir>/expat
make
make install
```

Comment: Can you explain the downvote? If you are on a locked down machine without root and the dependencies are not installed, it gets you a working version of Git in 5 minutes.

Comment: Did not work unfortunately. "make" on the git step says "zlib.h: No such file or directory"

Comment: Worked for me. there was no autoconf so i had to generate config on  EC2 and then copy it to my server

Comment: @phivo you can overcome that error with:
`cp /home/$(whoami)/install/zlib_install/include/zlib.h zlib.h` and `cp /home/$(whoami)/install/zlib-1.2.13/zconf.h zconf.h` before you make git. (if you built `zlib` into ~/install/zlib_install`. For me it this solution still throws error: `cannot find -lz`.

Answer (score 14):

This is what I ended up doing, the main trick being the make flags:

```
wget -O git.tar.gz https://github.com/git/git/archive/v2.17.0.tar.gz
tar zxf git.tar.gz
mv git-2.17.0 git
cd git
make configure
./configure --prefix=`pwd` --with-curl --with-expat
# ./configure --prefix=`pwd`
# Make flags from https://public-inbox.org/git/CAP8UFD2gKTourXUdB_9_FZ3AEECTDc1Fx1NFKzeaTZDWHC3jxA@mail.gmail.com/
make NO_GETTEXT=Nope NO_TCLTK=Nope
make install NO_GETTEXT=Nope NO_TCLTK=Nope
```

Credits:

1. 79E09796's answer above was a good tip, but didn't work for my case on Cloudways and did not require compiling curl and expat.
2. A random email record I found on the internet: https://public-inbox.org/git/CAP8UFD2gKTourXUdB_9_FZ3AEECTDc1Fx1NFKzeaTZDWHC3jxA@mail.gmail.com/

Comment: Note that you should drop the `-O git.tar.gz` or update the following commands to use this name instead of the one with the version

Comment: Does not work. I get `fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @Nathan I pinned the wget to v2.17.0 so it should work.

Comment: @IsaacGregson sounds like you need to install zlib somehow, which most linux systems have installed already.

Answer (score 12):

A related answer is https://askubuntu.com/a/350.

I could get it work with the third method proposed:

```
apt-get source git
cd git_vXXX
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
```

I don't know why, but when I had tried to install from the source download from github instead, I had a lot of problems with missing dependencies

Comment: It works only if `/etc/apt/source.list` is configured with source repositories.

Answer (score 9):

## Overkill workaround

Install Anaconda as a user and install git with conda.

### Advantages

Anaconda can be installed as user, and a conda environment can be created which can help you to install other packages. This way you don't need to compile git from source, nor you need to install libcurl and perl, so you won't get the error

`git: 'remote-https' is not a git command. See 'git --help'`

after successfully compiling git.

### Steps to install Anaconda, then git

1. read the [Anaconda installation manual](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/) which points to the [download page's](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#linux) [shell script file](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh).
2. Download the script file:

   - copy to your local machine and then copy with scp (e.g. [winscp](https://winscp.net)) to the Linux machine or
   - use a terminal on the Linux machine and issue `wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh`.
3. add executable rights to yourself on the file by issuing `chmod +x Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh`
4. follow the installation instructions where you can also specify into which folder you want to install anaconda
5. after installation, chose one of the possibilities below to successfully invoke git later:

   1. you either activate a conda environment, which is useful e.g. if you need to create different conda environments (it is common if you work with python). To activate an environment, you need to ask the installer (at the end of the installation) to add the conda initialization code into your `~/.bashrc` file [see below]. Using this method, your path won't be polluted, and you will see if conda-related binaries are also in your current path. Or you can
   2. add the installed bin's folder to your path, e.g. if you installed anaconda into `/home/myusername/anaconda3`, it will be in `/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin`. Your new executable file `conda` will be also there which will help you to install packages like git, python or pandoc, or
   3. cd into the binary folder of anaconda, e.g. `cd /home/myusername/anaconda3/bin`, and execute the commands below.
6. don't forget to take into effect the new settings by, e.g., closing and opening the terminal again if you selected method 1. or 2. in point 5. If you selected 1, you will see something like `(base) myusername@servername` indicating you are using the base conda environment.
7. Now you can [**install git using conda**](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/git) by issuing `conda install -c anaconda git`.

Your `.bashrc` will contain likes like this if you told the Anaconda installer to initialize conda for you:

```sh
# content of your .bashrc in your home dir
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/myusername/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/myusername/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Comment: This works for me. I don't have root on Cent OS so I have to install everything from source. But I still got errors like `git: 'remote-https' is not a git command`. I did some search and it looks like that I need to install `libcurl-devel` but I couldn't find its source, only rpm was found. So I tried your solution and finally can install linuxbrew correctly.  After installation, `brew install autojump` gives me two errors: it's not using a newer version of curl I manually installed and neither the anaconda git. I tried `export HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_FILTERING=1 && brew install autojump` and it works

Comment: As all the other answers fail, this is the solution for me