# How to install Git on Linux without admin rights (locally)

Tags: linux, git

How can I install Git without admin rights (locally) on Linux?

Compiling and installing from [source](https://github.com/git/git) with `make` and `make install` does not work due to missing dependency libraries.

Comment: `./configure --prefix=~/local/ && make && make install`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Git with non-root user account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039416/installing-git-with-non-root-user-account)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the [source code](https://github.com/git/git/archive/master.zip) to your home directory and unzip it.
2. Some dependency libraries are optional and can be disabled.  The following will disable all of them.  You may try disabling the ones you are missing and see if your installation succeeds.

.

```
make prefix=~/local/git NO_PERL=YesPlease NO_OPENSSL=YesPlease NO_CURL=YesPlease NO_TCLTK=YesPlease NO_EXPAT=YesPlease NO_GETTEXT=YesPlease
make prefix=~/local/git NO_PERL=YesPlease NO_OPENSSL=YesPlease NO_CURL=YesPlease NO_TCLTK=YesPlease NO_EXPAT=YesPlease NO_GETTEXT=YesPlease install
```