# Git version built for Red Hat Linux

Tags: linux, git

I have a Red Hat Linux server where I need to install Git.

However, I can't use `sudo` or `yum`(I can only copy from my local machine).

Therefore, I'm looking for a version of Git built for Red Hat Linux. I found [this page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/) with tarballs, but they just have the source code and are not built.

Any idea where I can find an already built version of Git for Red Hat Linux?

Comment: What's wrong with building from source? You can get an RPM and unpack it without root rights, but I'm not sure that will work properly then.

Comment: I can't build it locally. I'm getting `fatal error: 'libintl.h' file not found`. To solve this, I need to install something(which I can't).

Comment: I think you should be able to get the build dependencies in place without installing something. But I never did this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Git with non-root user account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039416/installing-git-with-non-root-user-account)

Answer (score 1):

In fact i think you can try solve this problem in one of the two ways.

**First:**

```
use centos/redhat iso

Code:mount -ro /dev/cdrom /media ; cd /media/Package/ ; rpm -ivh git-corexxx
```

**Second:** Use RPMfind.net

```
Code: firefox https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=git
Code: rpm -ivh hftp://rpmfind.net/linux/Mandriva/official/2008.0/i586/media/main/release/git-4.3.20-14mdv2008.0.i586.rpm
```

wish this can help of you