# Install git on siteground shared hosting seerver

Tags: git

I have a **siteground host**, and granted ssh access over there, but want to install git or configure it on the server, can anyone tell me how. Because trying '`apt-get install git-all`' or '`sudo apt-get install git-all`' doesn't works!

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039416/installing-git-with-non-root-user-account

Comment: What does it mean: "doesn't works"

Comment: well i can't make any sudo command, but to install it i need sudo !

Comment: What about the linked post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039416/installing-git-with-non-root-user-account):

`You can download the git source and do ./configure --prefix=/home/user/myroot && make && make install`

Comment: Yes i did it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`git` is already installed on Siteground hostings. Here a couple of links you could find useful to start using Git on Siteground:

- https://github.com/delcon/siteground_git_deploy
- http://blog.netgloo.com/2016/01/28/deploying-a-laravel-application-on-sitegrounds-shared-hosting-with-git/

Comment: As of today, it's only installed on their "GoGeek" hosting level. They have two other lower-priced levels of service that don't have git pre-installed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install Git on SiteGround servers since it's pre-installed for all users and you can simply start using it.