# Install Git without sudo privilege

Tags: git, sudo, debian-stretch

I have a non-root account on a Debian 9 (Stretch) System and I want to install Git.

Since the account does not have super-user privileges, Git can only be installed locally, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039416/installing-git-with-non-root-user-account).

Following the accepted answer, I downloaded and extracted the latest Git version in local home directory (~/) and then I enter the extracted Git folder like

`$ cd git-2.33.1/`

When I run

`./configure --prefix=~/git-2.33.1/ && make && make install`

I get `./configure: No such file or directory`.

Is there anything I can do?

I also checked the `README` of git and when I run `make` I get `fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory #include <openssl/ssl.h>`

Comment: You are not really trying to install git - you are trying to compile it from source. Find a precompiled binary for your system and use that instead. Compiling requires all sorts of dependencies to be installed, which it does not appear that you have. Note though that you will have to manually, on your account, also install all of the dependencies which have not been installed on the system.

Comment: @fredrik thank you for your reply. I wrote install, because after searching how to install git without super user privileges, everybody mentioned this way. Sorry if it is not the appropriate, I am a new Debian/Linux user. Do you know where can I find the pre-compiled binary, and what do I have to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be not very easy to have something working if dependencies are missing.

What you can do, download the `.deb` to get the last git version, you can find it https://debian.pkgs.org/11/debian-main-amd64/git_2.30.2-1_amd64.deb.html

For example:

```sh
cd /tmp
wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/git/git_2.30.2-1_amd64.deb
```

Then extract it

```sh
mkdir git
cd git
ar x ../git_2.30.2-1_amd64.deb
```

You will get

```
total 5.3M
drwxrwxr-x  2 john doe 4.0K Oct 29 21:31 ./
drwxrwxrwt 29 root      root       16K Oct 29 21:31 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 john doe  16K Oct 29 21:31 control.tar.xz
-rw-r--r--  1 john doe 5.3M Oct 29 21:31 data.tar.xz
-rw-r--r--  1 john doe    4 Oct 29 21:31 debian-binary
```

Then extract the data part:

```
tar xvf data.tar.xz
```

and you get the binaries

```
╰┤suze ▶ ls -l usr/bin
total 4968
-rwxr-xr-x 1 john doe 3343280 Mar 10  2021 git*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 john doe       3 Mar 10  2021 git-receive-pack -> git*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 john doe 1733608 Mar 10  2021 git-shell*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 john doe       3 Mar 10  2021 git-upload-archive -> git*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 john doe       3 Mar 10  2021 git-upload-pack -> git*
```

Comment: After running `ar x ../git_2.30.2-1_amd64.deb`, I did not got any output in the terminal, so I didn't check the first you "will get" that you mention `total 5.3M drwxrwxr-x  2 john doe 4.0K Oct 29 21:31 ./ . . .`. I subsequently ran `tar xvf data.tar.xz` and got a large output which I believe are the binaries that  you mention after. Having the binaries, what should I do next? p.s. I am sorry for my late response.

Comment: You have the git binary into the directory `usr/bin`

Comment: And how should I use the binaries? I am a new user in the Debian OS, so I get that my questions are very basic.

Comment: Put the file into `~/bin/` and add `/home/youruser/bin` to the $PATH into your bashrc ou zshrc with `export  PATH="$PATH:/home/youruser/bin"`

Comment: I copied all files to `~/bin/` and updated the path, but when I ran `git --version` to check if git works, I got `git: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by git)`. Did I have to take any other steps after updating the path?

Comment: You need to download the deb file matching your debian version: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/git

Comment: Thank you Orel, needless to say how helpful you have been. Now the `git --version` command runs successfully, though it is only `2.11.0.`. Am afraid that this is the latest version I can get in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

> When I run
>
> ```
> ./configure --prefix=~/git-2.33.1/ && make && make install
> ```
>
> I get ./configure: No such file or directory.

You don't really need the `configure` script, but if you want it you can just say `make configure` and run that, if you're having trouble finding ssl you can `./configure --prefix=$HOME --without-openssl`.

But all that script does is make some easy edits and the Makefile comes preconfigured to install in your home directory and has lots of comments up top explaining how to set yourself up. For instance,

> ```
> # Define NO_OPENSSL environment variable if you do not have OpenSSL.
> ```

so you can

```
tar xf the.downloaded.tar
cd ./git-2.33.1
echo NO_OPENSSL = > config.mak
```

and you're all set up for

```
make install
```

to build without openssl support and install to `$HOME`.

Comment: I have problem running  `make configure`. I get `/bin/sh: 1: autoconf: not found`, so if I am getting it right, I cannot proceed to try the solution you suggest. Thank you for your answer, and sorry for my late response.