# Versioncontrol Repository in LAN Working copy in Web

Tags: version-control, continuous-deployment

I'm a newbie to version control systems, so please pardon my naiveté.

I want the repository to be on a networked path within our local area network (LAN) so that only local PC's can access it. The files that are edited should be on a server which is accessible via the internet.

Here is a diagram of what I mean:
[image]

The Internet server is an ordinary web server, but it offers WebDAV. Is there a version control system with which I can implement this setup?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. What you are trying to achieve is called continuous deployment. You can set up a git server locally and then deploy the build artifacts to the WebDAV server (and/or another server) online.

[image: GitLab workflow example]

| ⚠️ Note |
| --- |
| I **strongly** recommend not running your version control software (VCS) locally, but rather, having [a private repo](https://dev.to/olawanle_joel/github-repository-explained-like-i-m-five-52m6#public-vs-private-repository) on [GitHub](https://github.com/), [GitLab](http://gitlab.com/), [AWS CodeCommit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/), [Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/repos/), or [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/product) that you [clone locally](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-clone) for work. |

If you're *committed* (no pun intended) to local VCS, then you can use the set up below.

### Continuous Deployment

You can create a local [scheduled script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page) to check for critical events (like approved [merges](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-merge) on the main branch) of a target local repo. The script will then build the entire project and copy the build artifacts to the WebDAV.

There are almost an infinite number of ways to achieving this, so I will just link to some high level guides:

1. [What is a Deployment pipeline?](https://www.pagerduty.com/resources/learn/what-is-a-deployment-pipeline/)
2. [Continuous Integration, Delivery, and Deployment](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/introduction/)
3. [Windows Scheduled Tasks Azure DevOps Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deadlydog.WindowsScheduledTasksBuildAndReleaseTasks)
4. [scheduling continuous integration pipelines](https://circleci.com/blog/benefits-of-scheduling-ci-pipelines/)

The script can be as simple as copying files from the repo to the WebDAV; or, as complex as integrating, testing, building, and pushing build artifacts. The specifics (which scripting language[s] and how to schedule) depend on your OS more than anything. Here are instructions for Windows: https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/07/03/how-to-automate-powershell-scripts-with-task-scheduler/

### git Server on LAN

Before you can deploy, you need a repo. The following are steps (using Windows 10) to get your local git server going. If you are using a Linux flavour, please adjust the instructions accordingly.

1. Create a folder where you want to create the Git Server.

   [image: Git Server Folder]
2. Move into that folder, right click and select

   *Git Bash Here*

   option. This will open a bash command window in the current
   folder.

   [image: Git Bash Here command]
3. Run the command

   *`git init anyname.git --bare`*

   to initialize Git bare repo without the working directory.

   [image: Git Init command]

That’s it. You have successfully set up your Git server.

#### Connecting to Local Git Server

1. On your Git server, Go to control panel → Network And Sharing
   Center > Change advanced sharing settings. Select

   *Turn on network discovery option*

   and

   *Turn on file and printer sharing*

   option.
   [image: File and Printer sharing in control panel]
2. On your Git server, Go to control panel → Windows Defender
   Firewall → Advanced Settings → Inbound Rules. Enable

   *File and Printer Sharing (NB-Name-In)* on private,public
   profile and

   *File and Printer Sharing (SMB-In)*

   on private, public profile

   as shown below.
   [image: File and Printer sharing option in firewall]
3. Go to the folder you have created Git Server, right click and select

   *properties*. Under

   *sharing*

   tab, click

   *Share*

   and add

   *Everyone*. Set the

   *permission level*

   as

   *Read/Write*.

   [image: Sharing Permissions]

   [image: Add some users with read/write permissions and the rest with only read permission for Special]
4. Once the permissions are set, you will find a share path.

   [image: Share Path]
5. Go to second Windows PC and open Git terminal and type

   *`git clone //GitServerName/PathToGitServerFolder.git` *

   command.

   [image: asciicast]
6. You can create new files and folders as if you do on a normal Git
   account.

   [[image: Git status]

   That’s it. You have successfully created your own Git Server
   and published on the network.

Comment: if I understand you correctly, the git client must be installed on the pc on with I commit changes. If so, then git wouldn't fit my needs since I cannot install any software on that pc.
Beside of that the client needs to know where to commit to / pull the data from.
If the git is within our local area network I think it would be necessary to setup something like dyndns. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't understand why I should rely on a third party provider like Github. What if the service is discontinued or there is a data leak. These are exactly the reasons why I want to have the repo within our company LAN. Could you please explain this.

Comment: @AlexanderBehling You don't necessarily need to install `git` to use it. You can download the executable and run it as a standalone (portable) file. See 
- https://gist.github.com/r-a-y/da6c3b1b99aafcb3e97e311280aa9434
- https://superuser.com/questions/190056/git-vs-portable-git

Comment: @AlexanderBehling There are always trade-offs to consider when deciding between local and remote hosting of any files. However, I believe that the likelihood of local catastrophes are much higher than Microsoft or AWS going under. It is the same reason why a U.S.A. federal government bond is considered more reliable than giving a low-interest loan to your neighbor.

Comment: @Mavadat Javid
I wasn't aware that there is a portable version of git. The link you posted is for windows. The webserver I working with runs on Debian Linux therefore I need the portable client version for this os. Do you know if there is also a portable version for this os. If so I would appreticate if you could share the link where I could find it.

The server could run on my windows workstation. There I could installed the normal git setup and point the repo to be on our network drive. Furthermore I had to setup dyndns on our router to make the repo available to the webserver.

Comment: @AlexanderBehling You have two options for portable git on debain: Compile using special `make` flags or by using `conda`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50337056/1757756

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot compile or install on this server because I lack ssh access and the necessary permissions. If I could, there would be no need for a portable version. Therefore, it seems impossible to me.
And even if it were possible, I don't think it's worth the effort, since I'm the only programmer working on this codebase, and it's just a codebase we're talking about.

Comment: Currently, I have solved the problem as follows. I create a zip archive with the files that have been changed for each implementation, which is then unpacked on the live system using a script I wrote myself.
The old version is renamed and stays there until I remove it manually, which I will do after about half a year.
So I also have some kind of version control that works with the restricted environment.

Comment: @AlexanderBehling You don't necessarily need to compile on your target system. You only need to know your target machine's Linux kernel and CPU architecture. See [What exactly is a compile target?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/344599/what-exactly-is-a-compile-target)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way that I can think of, though it take a little getting used to is [GIT](https://git-scm.com/).

You can do this with local repo `C:/some/path/to/repo` and the upstream as `E:/webdav/location` or `//link/to/webdav`, and just push to upstream to update on the server.

Comment: I have thought about this as well.

But don't I need the git client on the upstream side. If so, that's a problem because I don't have permission to install software on that server. Also, I would need to be able to access the repo from the internet, which I could possibly solve using DynDNS. However, I don't know if it is possible to restrict this connection on IP level. Then I could only allow the IP of our web server.